# Apply filter on all annotated fields of a POJO (Java)

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, pojo

Imagine that there are such kind of POJO classes, that just keep data:

```
public class Pojo() {

  @AnnotatedProp
  String someField;

  SubPojo someSubPojo;

  String someOtherFieldA;

  String someOtherFieldB;
}

public class SubPojo() {

  @AnnotatedProp
  String someSubField;

  Integer someOtherFieldC;
}
```

`someField` of `Pojo` and `someSubField` of `SubPojo` are marked special with the `@AnnotatedProp` property.

I'd like to modify an object of type `Pojo`. All String fields with `@AnnotatedProp` annotation should be modified. A "filter" should modify the values of these fields, e.g. replace some characters inside.

I tried with FieldUtils / simple reflection, but I ended up in stack overflows (the exception AND this forum).

What would be the best way to filter these fields?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show the code that you've tried? I assume that you used `FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation`, what went wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I've written a recursive POJO filter/transformer doing just that, because I needed it for a project. Just cleaning up and getting green light for release, but the key points are:

- use `FieldUtils.readField(field, node, true)` for traversal - for getting all fields annotated with your Annotation, there is also a direct method `FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation()` but I needed a more flexible way to scan all nodes first, so I can drill down on sub objects
- you need to check against your own base package name to identify your custom POJO classes and only traverse those sub objects.
- once you have your annotated field, you can simply use `FieldUtils.writeField(field, node, getMyValueForField(field), true);`

Caveats:

- to avoid a StackOverflow for back-references (child->ancestor), I keep a HashMap and store the FQCN of the nodes I traverse into
- before rolling my own, I checked Apache commons `ObjectGraphIterator`, but found it not suitable for my purpose.